# JS error on production but not development rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ckeditor

I'm having some issues with JS on production.  This is my CoffeeScript:

```
$("form.edit_email_template").submit ->
    window.onbeforeunload = -> null
    $.each $("form.edit_email_template"), (i, v) ->
      if CKEDITOR.instances[$("form.edit_email_template[action='" + $(v).attr("action") + "'] .email_content_area").attr("id")]
        try
          $.ajax($(v).attr("action"),
            type: "POST"
            data:
              _method: "PUT"
              authenticity_token: $("form.edit_email_template[action='" + $(v).attr("action") + "'] input[name='authenticity_token']").val()
              email_template:
                sendLength: $("form.edit_email_template[action='" + $(v).attr("action") + "'] #email_template_sendLength").val()
                subject: $("form.edit_email_template[action='" + $(v).attr("action") + "'] #email_template_subject").val()
                content: CKEDITOR.instances[$("form.edit_email_template[action='" + $(v).attr("action") + "'] .email_content_area").attr("id")].getData()
          )
        catch error
          console.log(error)
```

On development, it works perfectly.  On production, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined
```

How should I go about fixing it?

```
CKEDITOR.instances => Object {et28: e, et31: e, et32: e, et36: e, et7: e…}
et: e
et7: e
et8: e
et24: e
et28: e
et31: e
et32: e
et36: e
```

All the DOM elements exist.
And if I paste in the JS generated by CoffeeScript into the JS console, it works

Comment: You can do better asking this question. Give us values for CKEDITOR.instances and if you can manually get the id? The element exists on the DOM or nor?

Comment: Hey, this your friendly reminder to stop and take a look at your code. Seems like you're serializing a form by hand - JQuery can do that for you. Seems like you're appending the authenticity token by hand - the rails Jquery plugin should do that for you. You're also sending the method (`data: {_method: "PUT"}`) as some kind of homegrown meta data. You should use the actual method-option in the JQuery ajax call instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your production.rb file :

```
config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
config.assets.precompile << '*.css'
```

I guess CKEditor or some of your js has not been precompiled.

Comment: Then why would it work when I paste the js into the console? anyways, ill try that

Comment: Maybe some of your js has not been precompiled then